# No me envia notificaciones aun celular especifico

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase, push-notification

Muy buenas noches compañeros tengo un problema desde mi app y es que estoy enviando bn los parametros desde mi app para enviar notificaciones : este es mi build.gradle/Module:app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.appwendy"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 2
        versionName "2.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.3'


    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'

}
```

El build.glade del proyecto esta bien

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Este es el FCM en cual recibo las notificaciones: y lo tengo declarado en mi manifiest.xml y se llama MiFarebaseMessagingService.java

```
    package com.appewendy;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import java.util.Random;

public class MiFarebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null){
            mostrarNotificacion(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

    }
    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    private void mostrarNotificacion (String title, String body){
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logorojo_box)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setColor(R.color.colorAccent)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setLights(Color.RED,1000,1000)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{1000,1000,1000,1000})
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setContentInfo("WENDY");
        //builder.setContentIntent(clicknoti());
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Random random = new Random();
        int idNotify = random.nextInt(80000);
        notificationManager.notify(idNotify,builder.build());
    }
}
```

en el manifiest lo tengo asi

```
    <service android:name=".MiFarebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Y este es el metodo que envio la notificacion

```
private void EnviarNotify () {

if (!TokenEmp.equals("")) {
    RequestQueue myrequest = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    Log.i("FCM es este ENTRE: ", TokenEmp.trim());
    try {

        json.put("to", TokenEmp.trim());

        JSONObject parte1 = new JSONObject();
        parte1.put("title", "Pedido Nro. " + NroPedido.toString());
        parte1.put("body", "Se ha enviado de wendy");
        json.put("notification", parte1);

        Log.i("json: ", json.toString());

        String URL = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, json, null, null) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                Map<String, String> header = new HashMap<>();
                header.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                header.put("Authorization", "Key=COLOCO BIEN MI CLAVE DEL SERVIDOR");
                return header;
            }
        };
        myrequest.add(request);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Todo esto lo pruebo desde un el post de chrome y me funciona bien pero desde la app... no me hace nada ni envia ningun tipo de error. no si me hace falta algo para enviar mensajes que de pronto yo no haya colocado algun servicios ... Muchas gracias y perdonen la hora pero la verdad es que ya le he tirado muchas horas a esto. copio el json generado y lo pego en el emulador POST y lo envia. POR FAVOR NECESITO AYUDA URGENTE...GRACIAS

Comment: Revisaste el LogCat si se muestra algún mensaje de error? , recibes información en onMessageReceived() ?

Comment: muchas gracias amigo jorgesy ya lo pude solucionar ...de ante mano gracias muy amable.

Comment: Ok @HumbertoRafael, puedes agregar una respuesta en base a [ask] o eliminar la pregunta ya que encontraste la solución, saludos.

Comment: Compañeros la respuesta que me dio tanto dolor de cabeza y tranochadas es que para las notificaciones hay que tener encuenta: para primer plano debe enviar la etiqueta notificacion: ejemplo asi:
parte1.put("title", "Pedido Nro. " + NroPedido.toString());
        parte1.put("body", "Se ha enviado de wendy");
        json.put("notification", parte1);